# Determine how many characters in text are within another text entry in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table where there is a column of type 'text'.  I know I can compare two entries to see is they are the same using a simple select statement.  Is there a way to compare two entries and return how similar they are?  More specifically, can it say how many characters are different between the two?

For example, suppose one entry is:

```
This is a line.
```

And another that is:

```
This is a line.  And another.
```

I believe I can write a select statement that says the first in contained in the second.  But is there a way to alert me that the first is in the second AND there are 15 extra characters in the 2nd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Levinshtein distance http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#552

Answer (score 0):

You can use LENGTH along with LIKE to do this. E.g.:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES("HELLO WORLD");
select LENGTH(name)-length("HELLO") from test where name like "%HELLO%";
```

So you'd need to programmatically replace HELLO with whatever the string was you wanted to search for.

Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply measure the length of both as strings with `char_length()` and subtract the difference?
[MySQL: char_length()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length)

(Note that `length()` and `char_length()` return different values!)