# How to tell if one string is contained within another text element in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I asked this question earlier:

[How to get delta between two text items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057597/determine-how-many-characters-in-text-are-within-another-text-entry-in-mysql/11057686#11057686)

But I also need a more binary answer.  That is, is there a way to tell if one text entry contains another.   Again the example:

```
This is a line.
```

and

```
This is a line.  And another.
```

Is there a simple way in MySQL to tell the first is contained in the second?  Both of these items are entries in a column that is of type text.

UPDATE:

My table looks like this

id INT,
mytext text

So, what I'd REALLY like to do is write a query that answers the following question:

Find all records in this table where mytext is contained in mytext_for_another_record where id=SOMENUMBER.

Maybe better put:
Find all records where id=123 and mytext(for id 123) is contained in the record.

So I'm scanning the entire table for records that contain the text for the entry where id=123.

Example data:

### id | text

1  |  this is a line
2  |  this is a line and here is another
3  |  random
4  |  random this is a line

Now, rather than short text entries, suppose the text was VERY long, like 1000 characters.  Suppose I wanted to find all records in the database that contained the text that was in record 1.  Is the only way to do so to say `LIKE '%this is a line%'` ?  Is there a way to look by giving the id of the record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [INSTR(haystack, needle)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) function, and compare it to 0. If 0, `haystack` does not contain `needle`. You could also do it with `LIKE` operator and wildcards (`%`), but you'd have to escape the `%` signs.

Answer (score 0):

This should return you all of the lines containing the given text:

```
SELECT id, line FROM lines WHERE line LIKE '%This is a line.%';
```

The fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5451f/3).

Comment: So I know I can do that for text I have, but is there a way to do so without writing out the text itself?  For example, reference a unique id for the field vice the text.  The text could be several lines of text.  Rather than checking the text I'd like to say "rec.A's text is in rec.B's text"

Comment: Assuming that you have a unique identifier on the table you are querying, you can just include that in the select part of the statement (e.g. `line_id`)

Comment: The feeling's mutual ;) Maybe some clarification on your question would help. Input with desired output.

Comment: I edited my question but to re-iterate (in the event you did not see/get alerted)  Maybe better put: Find all records where id=123 and mytext(for id 123) is contained in the record.

So I'm scanning the entire table for records that contain the text for the entry where id=123.

Comment: @WildBill I've posted a fiddle as an example. Maybe you can expand on the data set. If you're already filtering on the id (123) then you're only going to get a single record from the database.

Comment: Unsure what fiddle is, let me look into it so I know how to use it and get help.  I updated my example again, hopefully a touch more clear...   Thanks for the help/time thus far.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the function `LOCATE`. If the 1 string is present in another you would get a number else 0.

The function is `LOCATE(substr,str)`. 
For details have a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate)

Answer (score 0):

you can also use concat():

```
SELECT id, searched,text FROM table_name WHERE text LIKE concat('%', searched, '%');
```